# How to use ELSE statement in .bat file that has multiple IF statements?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm writing a Windows batch file to enable, disable or make manual a Windows Service.

How would you use an ELSE statement if you have multiple IF options?

For example:

```
if /I "%c%" EQU "A"  goto :automatic
if /I "%c%" EQU "M"  goto :manual
if /I "%c%" EQU "D"  goto :disabled
```

I need an ELSE statement to send the script to an ECHO line that returns an error message if the user enters *anything other than* **A**, **M** or **D**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make I suggest using the `CHOICE` command.  Which only allows the user to enter in a valid option.

Answer (score 3):

[Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576) already showed you the perfect solution in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837583).

I want to show you how complicated it were in case you really wanted to use `else` clauses.
Let us stick to the following code:

```cmd
if /I "%c%" EQU "A"  goto :automatic
if /I "%c%" EQU "M"  goto :manual
if /I "%c%" EQU "D"  goto :disabled
echo Wrong user input!
```

1. Separate `if`/`else` statements:

   The parentheses are mandatory; the `:message` block can be elsewhere in the script:

   ```cmd
   if /I "%c%" EQU "A"  goto :automatic
   if /I "%c%" EQU "M"  goto :manual
   if /I "%c%" EQU "D" (goto :disabled) else goto :message

   :message
   echo Wrong user input!
   ```
2. Nested `if`/`else` statements:

   ```cmd
   if /I "%c%" EQU "A" (goto :automatic) else (
       if /I "%c%" EQU "M" (goto :manual) else (
           if /I "%c%" EQU "D" (goto :disabled) else (
               echo Wrong user input!
           )
       )
   )
   ```

   Or written in a different way:

   ```cmd
   if /I "%c%" EQU "A" (
       goto :automatic
   ) else if /I "%c%" EQU "M" (
       goto :manual
   ) else if /I "%c%" EQU "D" (
       goto :disabled
   ) else (
       echo Wrong user input!
   )
   ```

   Or more compact:

   ```cmd
   if /I "%c%" EQU "A" (goto :automatic
   ) else if /I "%c%" EQU "M" (goto :manual
   ) else if /I "%c%" EQU "D" (goto :disabled
   ) else echo Wrong user input!
   ```

As you can see, Ken White's solution is still the simplest and most legible one.

---

By the way, [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837408/how-to-use-else-statement-in-bat-file-that-has-multiple-if-statements#comment70861269_41837408) suggested a very good alternative, namely the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html):

```cmd
choice /C AMD /N /M "Select mode - [A]utomatic, [M]anual or [D]isabled: "
if ErrorLevel 3 goto :disabled
if ErrorLevel 2 goto :manual
if ErrorLevel 1 goto :automatic
goto :eof
```

Comment: Why does this keep happening? I'm trying a different website because you guys banned me from here...

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another `goto` without a condition will work:

```
if /I "%c%" EQU "A"  goto :automatic
if /I "%c%" EQU "M"  goto :manual
if /I "%c%" EQU "D"  goto :disabled
goto :ErrorInfo
```

If none of the first three are acceptable, the code *falls through* to the last one, which would take them to whatever code you want to execute if an unacceptable value was entered (or none at all).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give that a try... Just out of curiosity though: Is there any way to form the same function but by using ELSE statements?

Comment: Not the way your `if` statements are written.

Comment: Could you provide an alternate way of writing that code as compatible with ELSE statements? I think I understand how to use IF with parentheses followed by ELSE but can only do that for a binary (single instance of IF) option. Not sure how to do it when there are more than 2 possible branches at one user decision.

Comment: There isn't one for the type statement you're using. I think I've said that a couple of times now. :-) There are for compound `if` statements (`if somecond do (<multiple statements here>) else (<other statements here>)`, but not for the single line `test->goto` as you're using. Why are you trying to over-complicate your code? The single line I showed you is the proper solution; I don't know why you're fighting so hard not to use it.

Comment: I'm simply interested in increasing my knowledge of various ways to code batch files. :) I'm more than grateful for the solution you've already provided, it works very effectively. My searches on IF / ELSE statements haven't yielded effective results yet.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating single letter user input can be eased if you append the letter(s) to a label prefix and check aginst a given set:

```
@Echo off
:Cont
Set MSG="Press [A]utomatic, [M]anual or [D]isabled :"
Set Choices=AMD
Set /P c=%MSG%
Echo:%Choices%|Find /i "%c:~0,1%" >NUL 2>&1 && Goto :Choice%c% || Goto :BadChoice

:Badchoice
Echo %c% is a bad choice
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceA
Echo ChoiceA
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceM
Echo ChoiceM
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceD
Echo ChoiceD
Goto :Cont
```

Or very similar incorporating Squashman's suggestion with choice.exe (here also with a 10 second timeout on the first letter):

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Cont
Set MSG="Press [A]utomatic, [M]anual or [D]isabled :"
Set Choices=AMD
CHOICE /C %Choices% /T 10 /D %Choices:~0,1% /M %MSG%
Set /A _=%Errorlevel% - 1
If %_% lss 255 Goto :Choice!Choices:~%_%,1!

:Badchoice
Echo %c% is a bad choice
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceA
Echo ChoiceA
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceM
Echo ChoiceM
Goto :Cont

:ChoiceD
Echo ChoiceD
Goto :Cont
```

Comment: Though valid, your use of a variable called `"_"` (underscore) is not common. IMHO the only purpose of use non-letter names in variables and `for` replaceable parameters is confusing people...

Comment: What if `c` is empty, or if the user enters `AM`, `MD` or `AMD`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "options=AMD"


if "!options:%c%=!" neq "%options%" (
   goto :option-%c%
) else (
   goto badOption
)


:option-A automatic
echo Automatic
goto continue

:option-M manual
echo Manual
goto continue

:option-D disabled
echo Disabled
goto continue
```

First, a string with valid options is defined. Then, the `if` command check if `%c%` is one of such options; if the answer is Yes, the `goto :option-%c%` command *directly jumps* to the desired label without the use of any additional `if`. This method is very efficient, specially if there are a lot of different options. If you want to add more options just add letters to the string, *not* additional `if` commands.

Comment: What should happen if the user enters `AM` or `MD`?

Comment: @aschipfl: Yes, of course! A simple solution is to use `%c:~0,1%` instead `%c%` (like in LotPings' answer), but a better one is insert a space as delimiter in both the string and the `if` command; for example: `set "options= A M D "` and `for /F %%c in ("%c%") do if "!options: %%c =!" neq "%options%" ( goto :option-%%c`. In this way is possible to have single- or multiple-characters options and also eliminates heading spaces from `%c%`. BTW, this problem is not entirely solved in LotPings' answer...

Comment: I like your second option! The first one fails in case `c` is empty, unless you insert `set "c= "` before `set /P`. Yes, I just commented on LotPings' answer...